# Recreating Gitolite-admin Repo

Tags: git, repository, gitolite, git-clone

I have taken over a project where the previous admin provided no help, no documentation and no handover...I am trying to clone the gitolite-admin repo so that I can add myself as a user.

The issue is that when I run

```
git clone gitolite@repo1:gitolite-admin.git
```

I receive the error

```
R access for gitolite-admin DENIED to macbook
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

With the server's conf/gitolit.conf file containing

```
repo    gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   macbook
```

My repositories contains gitolite-admin.git amongst others, and I successfully ran

```
git clone gitolite@repo1:wp_of_travel
```

When I run

```
ssh gitolite@repo1 info
```

I am returned a number of projects, but gitolite-admin is not listed there.

Is my situation hopeless or am I missing something where I can reconstruct the repo and clone it again?

I do have full control over the server if that helps...

Any help or advice on this matter is more than welcome.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I run

```
ssh gitolite@repo1 info
```

> I am returned a number of projects, but gitolite-admin is not listed there.

This is normal: if macbook isn't registered in that project in the `gitolite.conf` of the repo (not your own local `gitolite.conf`, but the one currently stored in the `gitolite-admin.git` repo), you won't see it listed.

If you have access to the server, you can clone the `gitolite-admin.git` locally (file protocol, no ssh here), add your name (after your public ssh key), push back, and run `gitolite setup` (if you are using gitolite v3), in order for gitolite to update the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` files.

---

With a gitolite V2, the page **`gl-admin-push`: bypassing gitolite for the gitolite-admin repo** is helpful:

> Clone the repo to some safe location and cd to it:

```
cd /tmp
git clone ~/repositories/gitolite-admin.git
cd gitolite-admin
```

> Make whatever changes you want to that clone and commit. You can add new keys, change the conf file, or anything at all that needs fixing up. You can even reset to an older commit (rewind) if that is the simplest way to fix up some config problem that may have lost you your access.
>
> When done, instead of `git push <push arguments>`, use this program instead.
>   For example, instead of `git push -f`, use **`gl-admin-push -f`**.

The [OP edwardgd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166885/edwardgd) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631555/recreating-gitolite-admin-repo#comment18701770_13631762):

> Looks like the previous sysadmin had done a failed installation to root as well as to the user gitolite, that was why I was getting sooo confused.
>   For reference the `adminpush` method is very simple once you know where to apply it.

Comment: will running the gitolite setup command destroy any of the previous settings? Also I updated my text to say that macbook is on the servers conf/gitolite.conf not my own. I used incorrectly 'my' as I am now taking over the project. (thanks for the speedy response and help)

Comment: @edwardgd with gitolite V3, no: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/setup.html and http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/emergencies.html#lost-key can help too.

Comment: I may be being a retard here...but when I run gitolite setup, when logged in as the user gitolite I am returned `-su: gitolite: command not found`

Comment: in my /bin/ there is no gitolite. If this is where the standard installation is meant to be it looks as those the old sysadmin has sabotaged the server before leaving...

Comment: @edwardgd `ssh gitolite@repo1` will give you the version of gitolite you are using. If it is v2... frankly upgrade to V3 ;) But if no upgrade is possible, then use http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/adminpush.html to access / update that admin repo.

Comment: ah yes I was going crazy `gitolite v2.1-19-g36dfb85` I will look into upgrading it now. Merci once again :-) I will update

Comment: I am struggling a bit with this. Am I correct in thinking that gitolite is usually install in root's home directory? this setup seems to be install inside the user gitolite's directory

Comment: @edwardgd usually yes, but I can install it anywhere I want: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh. In your case though, before trying any update or installation, try http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/adminpush.html and update the gitolite-admin repo that way.

Comment: I got it sorted. Looks like the previous sysadmin had done a failed installation to root as well as to the user gitolite, that was why i was getting sooo confused. For reference the adminpush method is very simple once you know where to apply it. Thanks once again for your patience and time on this matter. If I could give you more than one tick I would :-)

Comment: @edwardgd great! I have edited and updated the answer to make the right solution in your case more visible.